# Find the distribution of some random variable connected to Wiener Process. Please, check my solution.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, solution-verification, brownian-motion

I need to find a distribution of $ 5W_1-W_3+W_7 $, where $W_t$ stands for Wiener Process $W_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0,t)$. **Is this solution right?**
$E(5W_1-W_3+W_7)=5E(W_1)-E(W_3)+E(W_7)=0$ and since $W_7-W_3$ has the same distribution as $W_{7-3}=W_4 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,4)$

$D^2(5W_1-W_3+W_7)=D^2(5W_1+W_4)=5^2D^2(W_1)+D^2(W_4)+2\mathrm{cov}(5W_1,W_4)=25+4+2\cdot 5\mathrm{cov}(W_1,W_4)=29+10\mathrm{min}\{1,4\}=39$

Hence the final answer is $(5W_1-W_3+W_7) \sim\mathcal{N}(0,39)$

If something is wrong can you point it out for me, please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: $W_7 - W_3$ has the same distribution as $W_4$, but it is not equal to $W_4$. (Otherwise $W_7$ would be completely determined by $W_3$ and $W_4$, which is NOT the case.)

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. So is $D^2(5W_1-W_3+W_7)=5^2D^2(W_1)-D^2(W_3)+D^2(W_7)+2(\mathrm{cov}(5W_1,-W_3)+ \mathrm{cov}(5W_1,W_7)+\mathrm{cov}(-W_3,W_7))$ ?

Comment: I think you might want to think of $D^2(W_t)$ as $\text{cov}(W_t, W_t)$ so you won't confuse yourself with the signs. Or better yet, think of $\text{cov}$ as the dot product. $D^2$ is just the square of the norm of the *vector*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write $W_t = \sum_{i=1}^t X_i$ where $X_i$'s are i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. You'll see that
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(W_t, W_{t+\ell}) = \text{Var}(W_t) = t
\end{align}
for $\ell \ge 0$.
From this, you can get
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(5W_1 - W_3 + W_7) & =
\text{Var}(5W_1) + \text{Var}(W_3) + \text{Var}(W_7) + \\
& \phantom{{} = {}} - 2\text{Cov}(5W_1, W_3) + 2\text{Cov}(5W_1, W_7) - 2 \text{Cov}(W_3, W_7) \\
& = 25 + 3 + 7 - 10 + 10 - 6 = 29.
\end{align}